# QGIS batch affine transformations

Tags: qgis, vector, batch, translation, affine-transformation

I have multiple polygon and line shapefiles on which I would like to apply a translation so I was wondering if it is possible to batch process them (maybe with graphic modeler ?) or do I have to change them one by one using affine transformation tool in QGIS 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Sry, for the late answer! You can run every Tool as batch process. Just rightclick an the Tool at the Toolbox and "Execute as batch process". More informations at: http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html . Be carefull, this dosn't work fine for all tools. I havn't found a way yet to process the files of a whole folder using the graphical-modeller.

Comment: I'll try it many thaks