# Scaling more than 1000 polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, centroids, xy, scale-factor

I have more than 1000 polygons, but they do not have the correct size and location. I have a table with the correct coordinates (centroid) **"x, y"** and  **different scale factor for each polygon**.

How can I automatically resize them and move them all to their correct location? In QGIS I used use the plugin "Transformation Afine" for individually polygons or scaling tool in advanced edit (ArcMap). My shapefile use EPSG:5367 (local system CRTM05).

[image: Fields]

[image: The batch processing does not recognize fields, only values]

The batch processing does not recognize fields, only values.

Comment: Does this help ? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93031/qgis-batch-affine-transformations The link in the post is 404ed, but googling "qgis batch processing docs" returns links to 2.0 and 2.2. right at the top.

Comment: No. The batch processing does not recognize fields, only values

Comment: The problem is that v.transform does not accept field names.

Comment: @underdark I need to find a solution in Arcmap, Qgis, phyton or any other GIS platform

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS you can create a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`. with a SpatiaLite expression to perform the transformation that you need:

```sql
SELECT
    ShiftCoords(
        ScaleCoords(
            ShiftCoords(
                a.geometry,
                -X(Centroid(a.geometry)),
                -Y(Centroid(a.geometry))
                ),
            a.factor
            ),
        a.x,
        a.y
        ) AS geometry,
    a.id AS id 
FROM
    "scale" AS a
```

With this query, we are:

- Translating each polygon to the origin of coordinates by subtracting the coordinates of its centroid from all its points: `ShiftCoords(a.geometry,- X(Centroid(a.geometry)),-Y(Centroid(a.geometry)))`.
- Scaling each translated polygon by the factor value stored in the `"factor"` field: `ScaleCoords(..., a.factor)`.
- Translating again each scaled polygon to the correct values of the `"x"` and `"y"` fields: `ShiftCoords( ..., a.x, a.y)`.